# ID пользователя pytelegrambotapi

Tags: python, telebot

Можно ли как-то узнать id пользователя так, чтобы он при этом не отправлял сообщение?
Например, есть команда `message.from_user.id`, но она покажет мой id.

Можно ли сделать команду `/id @пользователь`, для получения НЕ моего id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, нельзя. Боты обрабатывают только сообщения, но можно переслать сообщение необходимого вам юзера и узнать `id` через `message.forward_from.id`. Однако это не сработает, если у пользователя установлены соответствующие настройки приватности для пересылания его сообщений.

Если же вам просто надо узнать `id` без привязки к вашему боту, то лучше воспользоваться уже готовыми ботами, например, `@ForwardInfoBot`